# Some issues acessing asset files in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, permissions, assets

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and on my local machine I have the following image:

```
# Directory: MyApp/app/assets/images/
logo.png
```

I upload MyApp using the Capistrano gem and all seems to work as expected. However when I try to access my website through the browser at the following URLs

```
1) http://www.myapp.org/logo.png
2) http://www.myapp.org/assets/logo.png
3) http://www.myapp.org/images/logo.png
4) http://www.myapp.org/assets/images/logo.png
```

then I get an error page:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

In the log file I get:

```
1) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/logo.png"):
2) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/logo.png"):
3) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/logo.png"):
4) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/logo.png"):

  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

---

- In my local machine (development mode) I do not have problems.
- My remote machine runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Phusion Passenger 4.0.45,
  Apache 2.2.22.

Comment: Did you run an assets:precompile? This will give the app access to the files compiled, but it will not be placed simply in /public, like /public/logo.png. You will need to change your production.rb to allow serving of static assets

Comment: Also, could you check the contents of your `assets.rb` since Capistrano should run an assets:precompile on its own but it might not be configured to compile png images

Comment: @Russell - On the remote machine I try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and nothing seem to happen. How should I change the `production.rb` file?

Comment: @Russell - I do not have `assets.rb` file in my project. How can I check if Capistrano successfully executes the `assets:precompile` command?

Comment: Odd, the `assets.rb` file should be located in `config/initializers`, if it is not there it might explain why your assets are not compiling

Comment: @ivopatty - And what does the `assets.rb` file should contain? I think I do not need it.

Comment: If you want to serve static assets, change production.rb, look for config.serve_static_assets = t/f and  config.assets.compile = t/f change to what you need. The assets.rb isn't used with rails 4 and >. Rails asset pipline is now handled by sprockets.

Comment: @Russell - At this time I have `config.serve_static_assets = false` in the `production.rb` file. Would `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production mode be recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All assets that are compiled in Production have a fingerprint ID appended to the file name.  Therefore, in production, logo.png does not technically exist anymore.  What should exist now is logo-SOME_FINGERPRINT_ID.png.  See more info here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Also, if you wish to serve just the static image, you will need to put it in the images dir of the public folder.  You will then need to tell Apache or Nginx to serve static assets from that location.

EDIT:  To link to an image in your Asset Pipeline -

```
link_to(LINK_TEXT_OR_IMAGE_TAG_HELPER, image_path(IMAGE_NAME))
```

[Asset Url Helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path)

Comment: How should I state the `image_tag` method in order to use the static image located at `public/images/` thorugh out my app or in email?

Comment: You wouldn't as `image_tag` is an Asset helper.  Putting stuff in `public/images/` means it lives outside the asset pipeline.

Comment: @user502052 isn the actual issue that images are not showing on your page/email, or that you can not route directly to them in your browser?

Comment: I should use it in both web pages and emails.

Comment: @user502052 doesn't really answer the question.  Is the problem that the images aren't showing up on your webpages and/or emails, or that you can not route directly to the image in your browser (i.e. http://some.web.page/someimge.jpg)

Comment: By using the `public/` directory I can route directly to the image in my browser. By using the `app/assets` path I can not route it.

Comment: Correct, if your proxy server (Apache, Nginx) is configured to do so.

Comment: Are files in the `public` directory cached? What about logos? Should those be located in the `app/assets` or in the `public` directory?

Comment: Yes, the `public` directory is cached.  By rule of thumb, you should be putting all your assets in `app/assets`.  I merely showed you how you can serve a static asset from a Rails app; I did not say I supported using `public` to serve all assets.  May I ask why you need to route directly to an asset?

Comment: Yes, it is because I want to add a linked image in some email messages. By using files located in the `app/assets` directory it seems do not work but for those located in the `public` it does work.

Comment: Ok, so there is the actual issue; I had a hunch this was the problem.  My guess is you probably have your `link_to()` set up incorrectly. See my Edit for proper way to do linked image.